# Can I upload an app to windows store without compile with .net native tool chain?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-store

Can I upload an app which is not built with compile .net native tool chain and pass the analysis?

My app is using NAudio for playing pcm buffer, I found it would crash if it built with .net native tool chain.

However, I can't upload an app which is not built with .net native tool chain (even a blank project),

it always shown below

> The declared package dependency does not exist. Dependency:
>   Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0. Minimum version: 1.0.23430.0. Please
>   upload the .appxupload file generated by Visual Studio for the Store.

Comment: You should always compile in Release mode before you upload it to the store to ensure your application CAN be compiled with .Net Native.

Comment: I always compile in Release mode. just want to know is there a way to get appupload without compile .net native

Comment: or windows store app MUST BE COMPILED WITH .NET NATIVE ?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 10 UWP apps, when you are debugging in DEBUG mode in Visual Studio you are running against MSIL. When you are debugging in RELEASE mode you are running against .NET Native machine code. When you upload to the Windows Store, preparing the appxupload file, you are generating MSIL, not .NET Native - this is because inside the Store, the Store will use .NET Native to compile your code to x86, x64, and ARM architectures. When delivered to client machines, only the resulting .NET Native will be delivered. Not the MSIL.

> Check out my interview with the product team: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DevRadio/NET-Native-Performance-Optimizing-Your-Windows-Apps-with-NET-Native

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm new in windows development for couple months,

Comment: I have few questions
1. Does appupload file only can be built with configuration of "compile with .net native" ? (if I uncheck compile with .net native, I always get appbundle not appupload)
2. Even I can upload my app which be built in release mode and without configuration of "compile with .net native", store will also use .net natvie to compile my code, so if my app was not support .net native, it will crash in user-end eventually ?